# Using Emotion, new <style> is getting outputted in the <head> every time component's style is dynamically updated

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, emotion

I noticed that new Emotion 's are getting outputted in the  every time I update my style dynamically.

Follow an example in which every time DynamicStyleContainer is clicked, a new  is created in the head.

```
import { css } from "@emotion/core";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

import React from "react";
import _ from "lodash";

const app = css`
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100px;
`;

const dynamicStyle = (props) => ({
  width: props.appDimensions + "px",
});

const DynamicStyleContainer = styled.div`
  ${dynamicStyle};
`;

export default function App() {
  const [appDimensions, setAppDimensions] = React.useState(1);

  const increase = () => {
    setAppDimensions(appDimensions + 1);
  };

  return (
    <DynamicStyleContainer appDimensions={appDimensions}>
      <div id="app" css={app} onClick={increase}></div>
    </DynamicStyleContainer>
  );
}
```

Inspecting the head element:

[image]

I read the documentation and some examples and all seem to do something like this. Is this a normal behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is **expected behavior**, CSS-in-JS (like emotion), generates `className` on every unique style.

By frequently using a dynamic value like in your case, you will overflow your memory with such styles.

Instead, use `style` or `css` prop.

```
<DynamicStyleContainer style={{ width: app.Dimensions }}>
  <div id="app" css={app} onClick={increase}></div>
</DynamicStyleContainer>;
```

---

In `styled-components` you get a warning for it, don't know about warning in `emotion` but the fix is the same.

> Over 200 classes were generated for component Component. Consider using `style` property for frequently changed styles.